# Is there a working example of HTMLUnit log in and few clicks

Tags: htmlunit

Possibly showing Javascript Test Support

```
 
package htmlunitpoc;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class HtmlPoc {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) wc.getPage("http://www.google.com");
                HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("f");
                HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputByName("btnG");
                HtmlPage page2 = (HtmlPage) button.click();

    }


}
```

but i get:

Nov 17, 2010 3:41:14 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

Which does not help as it does not run as a Unit test, and shows Pass/Fail etc.

I am using netbeans 6.9.1

Comment: What does this have to do with the "https" in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you haven't written it as a unit test.   HtmlUnit is somewhat mis-named, as it's not a test runner itself, instead it's a "headless browser" which allows you to interact with a website from Java as if you were a browser.

Try this instead:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;

public class HtmlPoc
    extends TestCase
{
   public void test()
      throws Exception
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) wc.getPage("http://www.google.com");
        HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("f");
        HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputByName("btnG");
        HtmlPage page2 = (HtmlPage) button.click();
        assertNotNull( page2 ) ;
    }
}
```